# How to integrate mod_jk (apache2) with Wildfly 8.2.0-Final AS

Tags: java, apache2, wildfly-8, mod-jk

I am migrating an EAR application from **JBoss 6.1.0 AS** to **Wildfly 8.2.0-Final AS**. `standalone-full-ha.xml` is the configuration file used for running the server in **standalone** mode.

`mod_jk` setup is available utilizing **apache2** in the integrated setup and am trying to integrate the changes with `Wildfly 8.2.0-Final AS` as well.

Below line is present under `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:1.2">` subsystem:

```
<ajp-listener name="ajp" socket-binding="ajp"/>
```

As per the link https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/AJP+listeners, I modified the above line like below:

```
<ajp-listener name="ajp" scheme=http, socket-binding="ajp"/>
```

But, I am getting below error in `mod_jk.log` when hitting the application URL from the browser in a client machine (and even before the change, same error is obtained):

```
[Wed Aug 19 16:04:14 2015] [32461:140363260491712] [info] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (758): connect to ::1:8009 failed (errno=111)
[Wed Aug 19 16:04:14 2015] [32461:140363260491712] [info] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (1019): Failed opening socket to (::1:8009) (errno=111)
[Wed Aug 19 16:04:14 2015] [32461:140363260491712] [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1663): (ajp13) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=111)
[Wed Aug 19 16:04:14 2015] [32461:140363260491712] [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2673): (ajp13) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable), because of error during request sending (attempt=1)
[Wed Aug 19 16:04:14 2015] [32461:140363260491712] [info] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (758): connect to ::1:8009 failed (errno=111)
[Wed Aug 19 16:04:14 2015] [32461:140363260491712] [info] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (1019): Failed opening socket to (::1:8009) (errno=111)
[Wed Aug 19 16:04:14 2015] [32461:140363260491712] [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1663): (ajp13) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=111)
[Wed Aug 19 16:04:14 2015] [32461:140363260491712] [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2673): (ajp13) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable), because of error during request sending (attempt=2)
[Wed Aug 19 16:04:14 2015] [32461:140363260491712] [error] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2693): (ajp13) connecting to tomcat failed.
[Wed Aug 19 16:04:14 2015] [32461:140363260491712] [info] jk_handler::mod_jk.c (2806): Service error=-3 for worker=ajp13
```

PFB the **worker.properties** content:

```
worker.list=ajp13
worker.ajp13.type=ajp13
worker.ajp13.host=localhost
worker.ajp13.port=8009
```

**public interface** binding definition in **standalone-full-ha.xml**:

```
<interface name="public">
           <any-ipv4-address/>
</interface>
```

I am new to `mod_jk` and I suspect this is a change that needs to be done in `standalone-full-ha.xml` and I am missing something there. could anyone please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: What IP address is Wildfly bound to?
Have you tried to add -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true to JAVA_OPTS?

Comment: Many thanks .. owca. I have added <any-ipv4-address/> under <interface name="public">. JFYI that  -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true is already there in JAVA_OPTS.

Comment: Off topic, but don't use mod_jk. Use mod_ajp. Much easier. And same effect.

Comment: @EJP.. mod_jk is the existing setup in integrated environment and I need to re-use it with Wildfly.